# JDBC createArrayOf from ArrayList

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, arraylist, jdbc

I want to set a `WHERE IN` clause in sql, so I want to do a `preparedStatement.setArray(1, some_ids)`.

I can create a `sql.Array` like this:

`Array some_ids = conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", new Object[]{"1", "2","3"});`

But how do I do this with an `ArrayList<Integer>`?

```
ArrayList<Integer> array_list_ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array_list_ids.add(1);
array_list_ids.add(2);
array_list_ids.add(3);
Array some_ids = conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", array_list_ids);
```

I get

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[]
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert `ArrayList` to `Object` array to `toArray()`!

```
Array some_ids = conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", array_list_ids.toArray());
```

Comment: didnt work for me. can we get an example using Strings?